# How do I create fast backup of camera photos to cloud storage

Tags: applications, google-backup, cloud

One of my friends have taken some photos which were deleted by some elements by forcibly taking their mobile device and deleting them.

So I searched for ways (including app searches) for fast backup  newly captured photo by his camera to prevent this problem in future.

I need to find a way of doing this backup efficiently and automatically. Please suggest ways of doing that

Comment: Explicit app recommendations are off topic on this site. Edited your question to make it on topic. If you want only apps you need to ask on SE. Software recommendations

Answer (score 1):

You can try [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bitwisesl.android.uploadcam) app. It can instantly upload taken photos to Google Drive or Dropbox. There is option in settings to upload using cellular data.

Comment: Hello vasik988. The app concerned seems to have incredibly low installs count (100+) as of now. Are you affiliated with this app? If yes, please do disclose your affiliation along the lines of our site's policy. See [help] to know more about this.

Comment: Hi, no, this app just was at the top of Google search.

Answer (score 0):

I use [pcloud](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pcloud.pcloud), a cloud storage app. It has an automatic upload feature that uploads every photo or screenshot as soon as it is taken, even via mobile data.

Free version of the app gives you 5 GB cloud storage. I am not affiliated with the app but a happy user of paid version.

Alternatively, you can use [Folder sync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dk.tacit.android.foldersync.lite) to create folder pairs to sync with practically any cloud service of your choice  (see app description for supported clouds). But to make it upload automatically you may need to automate the process or you can upload on schedule. I use folder sync to schedule my device folders with Pcloud and Google Drive.

Answer (score 0):

I use official google photos app. It also provides free storage as well as also shows suggestions based on artificial intelligence for gifs, colleges, and colorpop etc.

**Update depending on comments**

I would like to clarify that photos app does not immediately upload photos but it processes all uploads in background.